# Intellij IDEA: Server Configuration cannot be run cause file does not yet exist. Use maven goal result as artifact?

Tags: intellij-idea

until now I deployed to a Glassfish server with the default IntelliJ artifact "Web Application: Archive". Now my built process got a bit more complicated with maven modifying several files.

In the glassfish configuration under Deployment, I substituted the Artifact to deploy with the direct war file and put the maven goal in "Before Launch: Another Configuration"

However, if mvn clean was run the war does not exist and I cannot run the configuration (because the external file doesn't exist).

Can I avoid having to run mvn package once manually? E.g. by making the output of a maven goal an Artifact?

Thanks!

Comment: IntelliJ has the option to invoke your build tool (Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc.) before launching a run configuration

Comment: In `Deployment` you can use `External Source` option instead of the artifact where you can specify the maven output directory to use.

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez I used this option in combination with @CrazyCoder's `External Source` option. Because the external source doesn't exist when I run the configuration, It doesn't start the maven goal I entered in "Before Launch"